# How to get items in Navigation Drawer to change view

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio, navigation-drawer

I want to make an simple app with a Navigation Drawer, which can open other views (News, Information, Gallery, Contact etc). So I opened up the latest Android Studio, made a new project that is compatible with API8>API19, to get maximum reach.

I chose the preset Navigation Drawer and clicked finish. I have figured out to change the names of the items in the Navigation Drawer, but how do I get these items to redirect to a new view?

I have tried implementing the setOnItemClickListener into the MainActivity as the Navigation Drawer site says on http://developer.android.com. But I can't seem to figure out how it all ties together, and it wont work.

**tl;dr:** I need help with making the items in the Navigation Drawer launch a new view/fragment, and probably an explanation on how it all works.

Here is the app project (Android Studio) https://www.dropbox.com/s/qfz9oul62dzt3rr/NTI_SHOWCASE.zip

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.christianarne.ntishowcase;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
    implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {


private static final int SETTINGS_RESULT = 1;

/**
 * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
 */
private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

/**
 * Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
 */
private CharSequence mTitle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.rgb(0, 153, 204))); // set your desired color


    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
            R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
}


@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
            .commit();
}

public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
    switch (number) {
        case 1:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
            break;
        case 2:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
            break;
        case 3:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
            break;
    }
}

public void restoreActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);


    actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
        // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
        // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
        // decide what to show in the action bar.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        restoreActionBar();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);


        return true;
    }
    if (id == R.id.action_example) {
        Intent intent_g = new Intent(this, Guide.class);
        startActivity(intent_g);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        textView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
                getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
    }
}

}
```

**NavigationDrawerFragment.java**

```
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment {

/**
 * Remember the position of the selected item.
 */
private static final String STATE_SELECTED_POSITION = "selected_navigation_drawer_position";

/**
 * Per the design guidelines, you should show the drawer on launch until the user manually
 * expands it. This shared preference tracks this.
 */
private static final String PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "navigation_drawer_learned";

/**
 * A pointer to the current callbacks instance (the Activity).
 */
private NavigationDrawerCallbacks mCallbacks;

/**
 * Helper component that ties the action bar to the navigation drawer.
 */
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerListView;
private View mFragmentContainerView;

private int mCurrentSelectedPosition = 0;
private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;

public NavigationDrawerFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Read in the flag indicating whether or not the user has demonstrated awareness of the
    // drawer. See PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER for details.
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    mUserLearnedDrawer = sp.getBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, false);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mCurrentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION);
        mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
    }

    // Select either the default item (0) or the last selected item.
    selectItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    // Indicate that this fragment would like to influence the set of actions in the action bar.
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mDrawerListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
    mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    });
    mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            android.R.id.text1,
            new String[]{
                    getString(R.string.title_section1),
                    getString(R.string.title_section2),
                    getString(R.string.title_section3),
            }));
    mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);
    return mDrawerListView;
}

public boolean isDrawerOpen() {
    return mDrawerLayout != null && mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mFragmentContainerView);
}

/**
 * Users of this fragment must call this method to set up the navigation drawer interactions.
 *
 * @param fragmentId   The android:id of this fragment in its activity's layout.
 * @param drawerLayout The DrawerLayout containing this fragment's UI.
 */
public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout) {
    mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
    mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;

    // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
    // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
    // between the navigation drawer and the action bar app icon.
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            getActivity(),                    /* host Activity */
            mDrawerLayout,                    /* DrawerLayout object */
            R.drawable.ic_drawer,             /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
            R.string.navigation_drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
            R.string.navigation_drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
    ) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            if (!isAdded()) {
                return;
            }

            getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            if (!isAdded()) {
                return;
            }

            if (!mUserLearnedDrawer) {
                // The user manually opened the drawer; store this flag to prevent auto-showing
                // the navigation drawer automatically in the future.
                mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                sp.edit().putBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, true).commit();
            }

            getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };

    // If the user hasn't 'learned' about the drawer, open it to introduce them to the drawer,
    // per the navigation drawer design guidelines.
    if (!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState) {
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
    }

    // Defer code dependent on restoration of previous instance state.
    mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        }
    });

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
}

private void selectItem(int position) {
    mCurrentSelectedPosition = position;
    if (mDrawerListView != null) {
        mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
    }
    if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
    }
    if (mCallbacks != null) {
        mCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mCallbacks = (NavigationDrawerCallbacks) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement NavigationDrawerCallbacks.");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mCallbacks = null;
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, mCurrentSelectedPosition);
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Forward the new configuration the drawer toggle component.
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // If the drawer is open, show the global app actions in the action bar. See also
    // showGlobalContextActionBar, which controls the top-left area of the action bar.
    if (mDrawerLayout != null && isDrawerOpen()) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.global, menu);
        showGlobalContextActionBar();
    }
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }

    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_example) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Example action.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * Per the navigation drawer design guidelines, updates the action bar to show the global app
 * 'context', rather than just what's in the current screen.
 */
private void showGlobalContextActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
}

private ActionBar getActionBar() {
    return ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
}

/**
 * Callbacks interface that all activities using this fragment must implement.
 */
public static interface NavigationDrawerCallbacks {
    /**
     * Called when an item in the navigation drawer is selected.
     */
    void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position);
}
}
```

Would it be better and easier to create an app with the Navigation Drawer from scratch, rather than using a pre-built?

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your code, and explain what it's doing wrong.

Comment: @ScottBarta I have edited the post now. I might not be doing something wrong, it's more that I'm a bit confused because the Android Studio generated Navigation Drawer files are veeeeery long and complex compared to some tutorials. If someone can explain how I can make the items in the Navigation Drawer (like "Kontakt") to open a fragment/view/layout that I can use. It's currently showing the same page when I press the different items, with only a number changing.

Comment: Would it be better and easier to create an app with the Navigation Drawer from scratch, rather than using a pre-built?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to setup a setOnItemClickListener on your drawerLayout(the id of the listview in your xml file)

Example:

```
    drawerLayout.setOnItemClickListener(new ListView.onItemClickListener){
    @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {

                displayView(position);
            }}

    private void displayView(int position) {

            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new FirstFragment();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new SecondFragment();
                break;
if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_layout_id, fragment).commit(); //
```

And you need to make separate java class for the FirstFragment and SecondFragment with whatever content you need.

Comment: Thanks for the help, much appreciated. The code you posted, will this be written within the MainActivity class?

Comment: Yes. It should be written in the class where you are getting the reference to your xml file for the navigation drawer.

Comment: So that will be MainActivity.java for you

Comment: Cannot resolve method 'setOnItemClickListener(ListView.onItemClickListener'. Almost everything turned red. Something that has to be declared in the beginning of the MainActivity?

Comment: Its setOnItemClickListener(new ListView.onItemClickListener)

Comment: Still all red. I changed Listview and tried an AdapterView, which made some of the red go away(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(

Comment: It feels like the best would be to just start from the scratch, to get a clean build. With less clutter that Google has included (might have to do something with AppCompat)

Comment: I gave you an example on what question you asked. Maybe your xml files are different. Its difficult to make assumption just on your java code. But the example i gave you works just fine. Try with a simple drawer first with the above code. And dont forget to upvote,accept if this was helpful. Cheers

Comment: Thanks for all the help mate. Will probably do a new project from scratch. Can't seem to upvote, need more reputation points :/

Comment: i stuck in same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30611704/how-to-set-visibility-on-navigation-drawers-items

Answer (score 9):

Well, I'll left this here in case someone needs help switching Fragments in an "Android Studio" Navigation Drawer project

The answer proposed by user2511882, uses the following:

```
fragment = new FirstFragment();
```

But the code generated by "Android Studio" uses:

```
fragment =  FirstFragment.newInstance();
```

(which is a better practice; see why [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245408/best-practice-for-instantiating-a-new-android-fragment))

That's why his answer doesn't work for your project.

In your case, you have to use something like:

```
  @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {

        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                fragment = FirstFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = SecondFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
                break;

        }
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
                .commit();
    }
```

In "Android Studio" it is also a good practice to read the comments and "TODOS" incorporated in the auto generated code.

best regards.

Comment: After calling the static newInstance() method in the case statement do I have to cast the result to (Fragment)?

Comment: Nevermind, I wasn't extending the support Fragment in my First / Second Fragment classes and I was referencing support Fragments in the rest of my application. All sorted now.

Answer (score 2):

get Item position in navigation view you can set first 0th position menu default by

> navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0); // default selected menu

```
displayview(navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0));

private void setupDrawerContent(final NavigationView navigationView) {
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                        displayView(menuItem);
                        return true;
                    }
                });
    }


 public void displayView(MenuItem menuItem) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_home:
               // fragment = new CheeseListFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_messages:
                fragment = new MessageFragment();
                break;
        }

        if(fragment != null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, fragment)
                    .commit();

            menuItem.setChecked(true);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

get Item position in navigation view you can set first 0th position menu default by

```
navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0); // default selected menu
```