# How to position menu items in Navigation View?

Tags: android, navigationview

My question is related to recently released `Navigation View` from `Design Support Library`. 
[image: menu]

I want to position `Log In` at the bottom of the `Navigation View`, how I can do this? 
My menu `XML` right now, look like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/navigation_sub_item_1"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_event"
            android:title="@string/home" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/navigation_sub_item_2"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_person"
            android:title="@string/profile" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/navigation_sub_item_3"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_labels"
            android:title="@string/tags" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/navigation_sub_item_4"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_settings"
            android:title="@string/log_in" />
    </group>

</menu>
```

Here is my layout :

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="@color/white_1000">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />

        <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
            android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/toolbar">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/content_frame"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

            <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                android:id="@+id/main_drawer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
                app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: For set  navigation view menu position [see this answer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31753244/4395114

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you want your "Log In" item to be fixed at the bottom of the Navigation View?

You can do that by nesting additional views/layouts within `NavigationView`. NavigationView extends `FrameLayout`, so you can wrap it around child views.

I posted more information on NavigationView footers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30611068/3449044). Also see the other answers in that post for more layout options.

**Edit**

FYI: If you use the "fixed footer" approach, you are basically removing the footer item (e.g. "Log In" in your example) from the menu. That means you have to implement click and other handlers yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I think navigation menu works like a listview. So Items will be placed in a list.

If you want one item to be placed at the bottom, you can customise within the NavigationView Tag in layout xml