# How to change the icons direction for menu items in a NavigationView?

Tags: android, material-design, navigationview

Hi I am using android **NavigationView**. I want to change the icons direction to RTL instead of LTR like this:

How can I do this?

[image: Example image]

Comment: do you try this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30613799/how-to-position-menu-items-in-navigation-view

Comment: There's a workaround for RTL items if you use https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer library. I couldn't find the fix for NavigationView.

Answer (score 3):

you can use listview inside the navigationview like what i did. the benefit of this is that you can have better control on this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
    >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/navigationmenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="192dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white">
    </ListView>

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

and nav item should be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/viewlist"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvlstName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"

        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and navcustomadapter like this:

```
package com.example.android.dezcook;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by Android on 6/4/2016.
 */
public class navCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    String[] result;
    Context context;
    int[] imageId;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public navCustomAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity,String[] prgmNameList,int[] prgImages)
    {
        result=prgmNameList;
        imageId=prgImages;
        context =mainActivity;
        inflater =(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }
    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return result.length;
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }
    public class Holder
    {
        TextView tv;
        ImageView img;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        Holder holder=new Holder();
        View rowView;
        rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.navitem,null);
        holder.tv=(TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvlstName);
        holder.img=(ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);
        holder.tv.setText(result[position]);
        holder.img.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
        rowView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                       @Override
                                       public void onClick(View v) {
                                           Toast.makeText(context,"you Clicked "+result[position],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                       }
                                   }


        );
        return rowView;
    }

}
```

finally call it in main activity like this:

```
 ListView lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.navigationmenu);
        lv.setAdapter(new navCustomAdapter(this,navItem,prgmImages)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just figure it out!

Try adding these attributes to `NavigationView`  in your layout file.

```
 android:layoutDirection="rtl"
 android:textDirection="rtl"
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

**Note:** It seems its working on API 17 and higher

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem.My app was "ltr" and I wanted to view drawer in "rtf" mode.
My solution:
In Navigation view I cleared :

- app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"
- app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_nav_header"

and replaced:

- include layout="@layout/drawer_nav_header"/>
- include layout="@layout/ly_custom_menu_item"/>

  ```
  <include layout="@layout/fragment_map" />
  <FrameLayout
      android:id="@+id/content_frame"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" />

  <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
      android:id="@+id/nav_view"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_gravity="right"
      android:background="@color/white"
      android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

      <!--app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"
      app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_nav_header"-->

      <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical">

          <include layout="@layout/drawer_nav_header"/>
          <include layout="@layout/ly_custom_menu_item"/>

       </LinearLayout>

  </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
  ```

ly_custom_menu_item.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearItemAnalysis"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/picSize_50"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/margin_dp_8"
        android:foreground="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless">

    <TextView
            android:text="navAnalysis"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_dp_16"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_analysis_menu"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearItemRouting"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/picSize_50"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/margin_dp_8"
        android:foreground="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless">

    <TextView
            android:text="routing"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_dp_16"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_routing"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearItemAddress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/picSize_50"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/margin_dp_8"
        android:foreground="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless">

    <TextView
            android:text="navAddress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_dp_16"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_address"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
   </LinearLayout>

   </LinearLayout>

 </ScrollView>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37rny.png)

Answer (score -1):

Try to set your navigation drawer item layout gravity. Example :

```
android:gravity="right"
```