# how to gravity to right in NavigationView

Tags: android, navigationview, layout-gravity

I need to put a menu item at right of text how to change menu item gravity to right in NavigationView ?

Comment: maybe it help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31103697/how-to-change-the-icons-direction-for-menu-items-in-a-navigationview?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:id="@+id/menu_group_2">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
            android:icon="@drawable/YourImage"
            android:title="Settings" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_about"
            android:icon="@drawable/YourImage"
            android:title="About" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

and change Navigation layout gravity to:

```
android:layout_gravity="start"
```

Navigation View:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/vNavigation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/view_global_menu_header"
        app:itemIconTint="#8b8b8b"
        app:itemTextColor="#666666"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />
```

Comment: I need the menu icon on the right of  text. But it did not change .

Comment: post your Activity.java and full activity_layout.xml because the code for navigation view is this, and it work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `android:supportsRtl="true"` into application tag in your AndroidMainfest.xml and set NavigationView gravity to start `android:layout_gravity="start"`

Answer (score 0):

i'm sure this will help you...

Try adding these attributes to `NavigationView`  in your layout file.

```
 android:layoutDirection="rtl"
 android:textDirection="rtl"
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

**Note:** It seems its working on API 17 and higher

Answer (score -1):

I think it's impossible.
You can use [Navigation Drawer](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) for this purpose.