# LTR drawer Navigation Menu Item in Android

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, right-to-left

hello I want to set LTR my menu Items in my Navigation Drawer .
English Alphabets is in left and Arabic alphabet are in right side , I want them be all in left side

[image: my drawer navigation menu]
[image: my drawer navigation menu]

**in manifast .xml**
i set         `android:supportsRtl="false"`
and it do not worked
 my manifast codes

```
    package="alla.brooska.com.alla">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="false"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".AboutActivity"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

i try it in Navigation drawer layout and it do not worked `    android:layoutDirection="rtl"

**my activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layoutDirection="ltr"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layoutDirection="ltr"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

my nav menu items

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
    android:textDirection="ltr"

    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">

        <item
            android:textAlignment="viewStart"
            android:textDirection="ltr"
            android:id="@+id/nav_setting"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp"
            android:title="settings" />
        <item
            android:textAlignment="viewStart"
            android:textDirection="ltr"
            android:id="@+id/nav_contact_us"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="contact us" />
        <item
            android:textAlignment="viewStart"
            android:textDirection="ltr"
            android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
            android:title="support us" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_about"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
            android:title="about us" />

    </group>

    <item android:title="@string/languages">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                android:textDirection="ltr"
                android:id="@+id/navkurdi"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_language_black_24dp"
                android:title="کوردی" />
            <item
                android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                android:textDirection="ltr"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_language_black_24dp"
                android:title="English" />
            <item
                android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                android:textDirection="ltr"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_language_black_24dp"
                android:title="فارسی" />

        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

Comment: You are setting rtl on layout xml it should be ltr

Comment: @Sirwan Rahimi set the properties of these `TextView` are `android:textDirection="locale"` and `android:textAlignment="viewStart"`

Comment: @Md.ibrahimkhalil i changed it , no deferent

Answer (score 2):

Set the `TextView` properties are

```
android:textAlignment="viewStart"
```

**OR**

```
android:textDirection="ltr"
```

From the use of these properties, it is an always start a text from left to right.

I am using for this including layout in `navigationView` which I can easily manage for localization.

**Like this**

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginEnd="-65dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-65dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <include
            layout="@layout/nav_header_main_navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

**nav_header_main_navigation**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/app_gray"
    android:gravity="bottom">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rlTop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="88dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:background="@color/appYellow">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:includeFontPadding="false"
                    android:maxEms="14"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    android:textColor="@color/app_gray"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/rlBack"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:clickable="true">
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ivBack"
                        android:layout_width="10dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        android:src="@drawable/back_icon_black" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rlBottom"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@id/rlTop"
                android:background="@color/app_gray">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/rlProfile"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ivProfile"
                        android:layout_width="19dp"
                        android:layout_height="19dp"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/icon_nav_profile" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvProfile"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/ivProfile"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ivProfile"
                        android:includeFontPadding="false"
                        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
                        android:paddingTop="1dp"
                        android:text="@string/profile"
                        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textDirection="locale"
                        android:textSize="15sp" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

its an example for your easiness to avoid menu and use normal layouts.

Here is more answers regarding above example [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31103697/how-to-change-the-icons-direction-for-menu-items-in-a-navigationview)

Comment: @SirwanRahimi please show your navigation item code?

Comment: I added nav menu to my question see it please .

Comment: @SirwanRahimi you are using menu for `navigationView` if you inclued layout in your `navigationView` it can easily manage. I update my answer please have look at it

Comment: how ? can you give me an example ?

Comment: Thank you I will try to understand your steps

Comment: @SirwanRahimi your welcome and please make a sure mark this answer if it's helped.

Comment: I will use your solution way , but maybe I need more help , can you help me use in your solution?

Comment: @SirwanRahimi yes sure dude

Comment: @SirwanRahimi please mark the answer if it's helped you.