# ScrollView inside a NavigationDrawer menu

Tags: android, android-scrollview, navigation-drawer

I want to implement ScrollView in NavigationDrawer template of Android Studio. What do I need to do? How can make the full Navigation menu scrollable? I have a lot of options are here, but I can't scroll & view all of them
[Demo Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hi4nR.png)

Comment: I add my answer please have to look at that.

Comment: any update about the future link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using for this including layout in `navigationView` which I can easily manage.

**Like this**

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginEnd="-65dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-65dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <include
            layout="@layout/nav_header_main_navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

**nav_header_main_navigation**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/app_gray"
    android:gravity="bottom">
  <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rlTop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="88dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:background="@color/appYellow">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:includeFontPadding="false"
                    android:maxEms="14"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    android:textColor="@color/app_gray"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/rlBack"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:clickable="true">
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ivBack"
                        android:layout_width="10dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        android:src="@drawable/back_icon_black" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rlBottom"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@id/rlTop"
                android:background="@color/app_gray">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/rlProfile"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ivProfile"
                        android:layout_width="19dp"
                        android:layout_height="19dp"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/icon_nav_profile" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvProfile"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/ivProfile"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ivProfile"
                        android:includeFontPadding="false"
                        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
                        android:paddingTop="1dp"
                        android:text="@string/profile"
                        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textDirection="locale"
                        android:textSize="15sp" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my whole **Navigation activity XML**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginEnd="-65dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-65dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <include
            layout="@layout/nav_header_main_navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here is a major factor to avoid `ViewPager`

**app_bar_main_navigation**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/app_gray"
    tools:context="com.barq.consumer.ui.home.MainNavigationActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/flMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </FrameLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Now in **MainNavigationActivity.Java**

```
public class MainNavigationActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.drawer_layout)
    DrawerLayout drawer;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_navigation);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
      //here is you can load your fragment without view pager
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.flMain, HomeFragment.newInstance(), HomeFragment.TAG)
                .commit();


}
```

And other clicks you can handle manually to load other fragments in frame layout and activities and drawer open and close you also handle manually use drawer object. Hope so you can understand it.

its an example for your easiness to avoid menu and use normal layouts in the scroll view.
Here are more answers regarding the above example [ULR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31103697/how-to-change-the-icons-direction-for-menu-items-in-a-navigationview)

Comment: Maybe you are Right.
But it's not working in my project.

Comment: @shaikatsaha can you upload your XML file then I will update it according to your scenario

Comment: my project is in GitHub. may I share the link?

Comment: @shaikatsaha you are using viewPager to manipulate your fragments, therefore, you are not getting this technique.

Comment: will you please share GitHub link?

Comment: sorry, brother, I don't have GitHub link

Comment: any other way 
mainly the project file